# Android Spinner from SQLite is acting weird

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-layout

I have 3 spinners

1) Array Spinner

2) XML Spinner and

3) SQLite Cursor Spinner

When I added my 3rd Spinner, the page started acting weird. The spinners 1 & 2 started showing up in the spinner 3 area. The values from Cursor are present in Spinner 3. When I select any value, `TOAST` works perfectly but the value doesn't get selected.

**Layout File: spinner_demo_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.training.sqlitelistviewdemo.SpinnerDemo">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Country"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spCountries"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog">

</Spinner>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Business Type"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spBussinessType"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/business_prompt">

</Spinner>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Shop Name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_Shops"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/select_shops"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog">
</Spinner>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

**My Java File: SpinnerDemo.java**

```
package com.training.sqlitelistviewdemo;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpinnerDemo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // uicontrols
    Spinner spCountries;
    Spinner spBusinessType;
    Button btnsubmit;

    //class members
    String businessType[] = { "Automobile", "Food", "Computers", "Education", "Personal", "Travel" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBusinessType;

    // local members
    String sbusinesstype,scountry;

    // SQLite Parameters Start

    private DatabaseManager dbManager;
    private TextView tv_Text;
    private Spinner sp;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    // final String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.SHOPNAME, DatabaseHelper.SHOPADDRESS };
    final String[] from = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.SHOPNAME};

    //final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.shopname, R.id.shopaddress };
    final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

    // SQLite Parameters End


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_demo_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        spCountries = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCountries);
        spBusinessType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spBussinessType);

        btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialize and set Adapter
        adapterBusinessType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, businessType);
        adapterBusinessType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spBusinessType.setAdapter(adapterBusinessType);

        // Country Item Selected Listener
        spCountries.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                scountry = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected Country : " + scountry, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        // Business Type Item Selected Listener
        spBusinessType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                sbusinesstype = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Bussiness Type : " + sbusinesstype, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
// SQLite Spinner Code Starts

        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        dbManager.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch_Shop();
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_Shops);
        // sp.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_demo_main, cursor, from, to, 0);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        //sp.setSelection(1);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                sp.setSelection(position);

                Cursor shopCur=(Cursor)sp.getSelectedItem();
                String shopNamecol=shopCur.getString(shopCur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.SHOPNAME));
                String Rowid = shopCur.getString(shopCur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Selected - " + shopNamecol + " - " + Rowid + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });



// SQLite Spinner Code Ends
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " + scountry + " and " + sbusinesstype,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

[Spinner Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGwvf.png)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please see the screen shot which is attached

Comment: Yeah but your screenshot is having 5 spinners!!

Comment: The 5 Spinners you see is one of my problems. I defined only 3 spinners and on the screen as you can see in the layout, the first 2 spinners repeat again. It is so funky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue ..Phew

Updated the below line

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_demo_main, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

spinner_demo_main - This is my Activity class - instead we should be giving android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

as below

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue declare the three spinners in java file and initialize them in java file

```
Spinner spCountries;
Spinner spBusinessType;
Spinner shops;

//class members
String businessType[] = { "Automobile", "Food", "Computers", "Education", "Personal", "Travel" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBusinessType;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspCountriesType;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptershopsType;
```

now add setOnItemSelectedListener and handle the using switch case .

It works fine for me.

Comment: Hi Jagteshwar, Thanks for the response. It still doesn't work for me. I have the 3rd spinner using SimpleCursorAdaptor. Which I had initialized below. The second spinner I am not using an Adapter.